# Is volatile keyword useful with .net core under intel cpu?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, volatile

I have tried few problematic cases where volatile helpful with .NET Framework. However under .NET Core I haven't found a single case that volatile is actually helping. Is memory model with .NET Core stronger than .NET Framework so that we don't need volatile any more ?

As an example the following code blocks indefinitely with .net framework if you build it with release mode but it doesn't with .net core. The reason is, in .net case the value is stored in a register and cached:

```
    class Program
    {
        static bool complete = false;
        static void Main()
        {

            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                bool toggle = false;
                while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
            });
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            complete = true;
            t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most people - including me - can't explain (accurately and precisely) exactly what `volatile` means or does (and it **isn't** "makes sure it gets re-read", that's an accidental bi-product of an implementation); so, virtually every time I see someone asking about volatile, they're asking the wrong question. What do you mean by "useful" here? What do you think it does? Note also: this is also hugely related to CPU and runtime; .NET Core on x86, for example, is very different (in terms of this) than .NET Core on x64. Then we need to talk about which exact version of .NET Core, etc...

Comment: I think we know. in CLR context volatile means: Yo compiler don't put the data into CPU cache. And yo CPU when ever you read this field aquire a read fence so that no other instruction can go before and when ever you write to this field aquire a write fence so no other instruction can go below. Sure different CPUs and different things. My question is towards if anyone is aware of a known change regarding the memory model with .net core.

Comment: @OnurGumus, It's not just "cache." I don't know exactly what `volatile` means in .NET, but in a certain other language, it means updates to the variable by one thread should promptly become visible to other threads. The caches in multi-processor computing hardware are just one reason why that's an issue. Another is compile-time optimization: If your code accesses a non-volatile variable with no other synchronization, then the compiler is allowed to re-write your code assuming that only one thread will execute it and, that no other thread will ever touch the variable.

Comment: "I tried it and it seems to work" is not the way to determine the correctness of multi-threaded code. Don't rely on observed behavior of the implementation. Read the documentation and see what `volatile` actually means. Your question makes a lot of assumptions about the underlying CPU architecture, which are not guaranteed by .NET Core or most other runtime environments. You have no idea, even in C, whether a particular variable will end up in a register. Even more concerning is that you seem to think `volatile` is somehow related to multi-threading; it isn't. Using it at all is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx), `volatile` in C# tells the compiler / JIT to issue instructions that prevent instruction reordering.  While the memory model of .NET on Intel platforms is normally strong enough that ordering would rarely happen, you never know on other platforms (for example ARM).

In other words, there is rarely need to use `volatile`, unless you are afraid reordering can break your code.  At the same time, when it comes to multi-threading, it is always best to be safe.

Comment: I have added a counter  example  to the question.

Comment: In your example, bool is a local variable.  As such, it cannot be `volatile`.  Then, what happens, is that the compiler optimizes the code so it doesn't evaluate `complete` on every run, despite that it is being "closured".  Such optimization is legal for C++ as well.

Comment: That doesn't matter. I have changed it to field same result. Adding volatile to the field fixes the issue. This doesn't happen even in .net core.

Comment: It does, as this doesn't always happen.  I've tried it many times but can never reliably reproduce the need to set `volatile`.

Comment: My impression is your article is accurate by definition. On intel there is no need for volatile. However due to a JIT bug above issue happens (that puts the variable to a register) In .net core it is fixed. So I think we can conclude on intel platform there is no need for volatile under .net core for the intel platform.